# Загрузка кода страницы при помощи Awesomium

Tags: c#, .net, awesomium

Пишу приложение, в котором должен присутствовать компонент *ВебБраузера*, но меня не устраивает то, что стандартный компонент  работает на движке *I*.

Поставил движок [Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/), но в стандартном компоненте было событие `DocumentCompleted`, происходящее, когда весь документ уже загружен. Тем самым мне было удобно вытягивать весь полностью загруженный код страницы.

Есть ли аналог этому событию в компоненте Awesomium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть OnDocumentReady, только нужно проверить свойство IsMainFrame, на вид вот так:

У них так же есть неплохая [документация](http://docs.awesomium.net/)

```
private void WbAwsOnDocumentReady(object sender, UrlEventArgs urlEventArgs)
         {
             if (wbAws == null || !wbAws.IsLive)
             return;


                 //Is Page Loaded? Main Frame Loads Last.
                 if (e.IsMainFrame)
                 {

                      if (wbAws.IsDocumentReady == true)
                     { 
                            dynamic document = (JSObject)wbAws.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document");

                          if (document == null)
                          return;

                          using (document)
                          {
                               dynamic textbox = document.getElementById("email");

                               if (textbox == null)
                               return;

                               using (textbox)
                               {
                                    textbox.value = "gaaffa";
                               }//end using

                          }//end using
                  }//end IsDocumentReady
              }//end e.IsMainFrame
         }//end method
```